# How do I use Python file in Nagios?

Tags: python, plugins, nagios

I'm trying to get a response from Nagios by using the following Python code and instructions:
http://skipperkongen.dk/2011/12/06/hello-world-plugin-for-nagios-in-python/

From some reason I never get to have OK from Nagios and it's always comes back with the message: Return code 126 is out of bounds - plugin may be missing

I installed nagiosplugin 1.0.0, and still nothing seems to be working
In parallel I have some other services (not python files) that work e.g. http check, current users, and SSH

What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to solve that for few days already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting Nagios to utilize your new plug-in is quite easy. You should make changes to three files and restart Nagios — that’s all it takes.

The first file is **/etc/nagios/command-plugins.cfg** (leave comment please if you know path to this file or analog in **ubuntu**). Assumed that plugin file is placed in /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/ directory:

```
command[check_hello_world]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_helloworld.py -m 'some message'
```

Drop down one directory to **/etc/nagios/objects/commands.cfg** (for ubuntu user should create cfg file in that dir **/etc/nagios-plugins/config/**):

```
define command {
    command_name    check_hello_world
    command_line    $USER1$/check_hello_world.py -m 'some message'
}
```

Save the file and open up **/etc/nagios/objects/localhost.cfg** (in ubuntu path to service definition files located in /etc/nagios3/nagios.cfg and by default **cfg_dir=/etc/nagios3/conf.d**. So, to define new service in ubuntu user should create cfg file in that dir, for example **hello.cfg**). Locate this section:

```
#
# SERVICE DEFINITIONS
#
```

and add new entry:

```
define service {
    use                 local-service ; Name of service template to use
    host_name           localhost
    service_description Check using the hello world plugin (always returns OK)
    check_command       check_hello_world
}
```

All that remains is to restart Nagios and to verify that plug-in is working. Restart Nagios by issuing the following command:

```
/etc/init.d/nagios restart
```

http://www.linux-mag.com/id/7706/

ubuntuforums.org - [Thread: My Notes for Installing Nagios on Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1986743)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply,
My problem is not resolved yet since I don't have the file command-plugins.cfg (I'm running Nagios 3.2.3-3ubuntu1)
when I tried to create this file and add it to nagios.cfg it raised an error. Under what section is command-plugins.cfg added in your nagios.cfg if at all?

Comment: @user2314782 did you install nagios-plugins package?

Comment: Yes, I installed the plugins and using some of them already. So as written above, I created the file command-plugins.cfg and added it to nagios.cfg (otherwise it wouldn't know it's there) under cfg_file=/etc/nagios3/command-plugins.cfg when I reload nagios it raise this error: unexpected token or statement in file commands-plugins.cfg . When I remove the line pointing to commands-plugins.cfg in nagios.cfg and try to reload - it reloads ok.
Also I made my python script file executable, but still it doesn't work :(

Comment: @user2314782 i think that your problem is ubuntu specific... maybe you already have command-plugins.cfg but with different name and maybe in other directory. Try to look for answer on ubuntuforums.org (if you find the answer, comment here plz)

Comment: After few days of search I found what caused the problem:
I created the Python file on my windows machine and copied it into the ubuntu. Apparently windows puts in different line endings to Unix and that was the problem! be careful when moving files from different platforms

Answer (score 0):

I had to prepend the path to python2.7 even though the shebang in the file specified it.

In the command definition I had this:

```
command_line /usr/local/bin/python2.7 $USER1$/check_rabbit_queues.py --host $HOSTADDRESS$ --password $ARG1$
```

Even though the top of the actual python file had:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
```

Even though the script executed and returned just fine from the command line without specifying the interpreter.

Nothing else I tried seemed to work.